# .NET RegEx to Find Backslash Inside Any Doubly-Quoted String

Tags: .net, regex, visual-studio

I'm wanting a regular expression that will match any backslash found inside a doubly-quoted string in my code. For example, the following should all match:

```
Dim testStr As String = "This is \ text"
Dim testStr2 As String = "\"
```

I'm wanting to do a solution wide search using the Find feature in VS.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
\\~([^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

`\\` matches a literal backslash. What comes next is equivalent to a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `~(...)` asserts, that `...` can *not* be matched at that point (without including anything more in the actual match). We use this to make sure that the backslash was inside a string. If it is inside a string, there will be an odd number of `"` between it and the end of the line. So `[^"]*("[^"]*"[^"]*)*$` matches if there is an even number of `"` between the backslash and the end of the line (represented by `$`).

This would cause problems with multi-line strings or quotes that are escaped as `\"`, but luckily neither exists in VB.NET, so you should be safe with this solution.

Note that this **not** a .NET regular expression. Visual Studio has [its own rather odd regex syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).